# Unknown skip error file read in python

Tags: python, file

Now  I have a text file which i outputted to 3 times using the following code.

```
def Final_Output():##// Edited
with open('A Class, A.T.I..txt', "a") as file_out:
    file_out.write("Full_Name :> " + str(Sur_Name) + ', ' + str(Name) + '\n')
    file_out.write("Date: >: " + str(Date) + "\n")
    file_out.write("Class: >: " + str(Class) + '\n')
    file_out.write("Range >: " + str(Range_Limit) + "\n")
    file_out.write("Score :> " + str(N) + '\n')
    file_out.write("Score_Percent :> " + str(Score_Percent) + '\n')

Name = "MohKale"
Sur_Name = "MohKale Surname"
Date = "16/9/2015 11:7:52"
Class = "A"
Range_Limit = "10765"
N = "10"
Score_Percent = "0.0"

Final_Output()
```

Then I created a program which reads the text file continuously (until the end) and then saves them to variables.

```
a = 0
with open('A Class, A.T.I..txt', "r") as file_out:
    for line in file_out:
        a = a + 1
        Name2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Name2)
        Sur_name2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Sur_name2)
        Date2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Date2)
        Class2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Class2)
        Range_Limit2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Range_Limit2)
        N2 = file_out.readline()
        print(N2)
        Score_Percent2 = file_out.readline()
        print(Score_Percent2)
```

Now technically the program does read the text file, and saves to variables, but the problem is the first time it reads the text file it skips the first line for some reason, the second time it looped it also skipped the first line but also the second one, then the third time it looped it read the 2nd line but skipped the third, this continuously happened skipping the next read file.

can anyone understand and explain the problem

furthermore by putting 
`print(line)`
it does print the missing lines, but this is way too random, is there anyway to prevent such an event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using a for loop AND iterating over the lines, use just one :)

I suggest that you remove the for loop and do just the `file_out.readline()`'s

```
with open('A Class, A.T.I..txt', "r") as file_out:
    a = a + 1
    Name2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Name2)
    Sur_name2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Sur_name2)
    Date2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Date2)
    Class2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Class2)
    Range_Limit2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Range_Limit2)
    N2 = file_out.readline()
    print(N2)
    Score_Percent2 = file_out.readline()
    print(Score_Percent2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your for loop is consuming some of the lines in the file independently of your other .readline() calls. Rather than doing

```
for line in file_out:
```

You will want to do something like

```
try:
   while True:
      a += 1
      Name2 = next(file_out)
      print(Name2)
      # ...
      Score_Percent2 = next(file_out)
      print(Score_Percent2)    
except StopIteration:
   print("Done!")
```